# ZF2 how to avoid sql query limit to add quotes in subquery

Tags: sql, zend-framework2, subquery, limit, quotes

I'm trying to set up a subquery in ZendFramework 2 and I got an issue with the limit function for a Select object. Whatever I do, numeric value is put between quotes and makes my query fails : I should get LIMIT 1 and instead I get LIMIT '1'.

Seems this is not the first time this issue has been encountered, I saw some have asked about this issue before (like 8 months ago) but without getting any proper answer.
I also saw this issue has been marker as resolved in 2012 (https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/2775) so I really don't understand what's happening there.

Here's my code in ZF2 :

```
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select( function (Select $select) use ($params)   {
        $sub = new Select();
        $sub->from(array('temp' => 'scores'))
            ->columns(array(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("id AS id")))
            ->where(array('temp.glitch' => array('None', 'Glitch')))
            ->where('temp.zone=scores.zone')
            ->order('temp.multi DESC, temp.score DESC')
            ->limit(1);

        $select->join('players', 'player=players.id', array('player_name' => 'name', 'player_url' => 'name_url'))
            ->join('countries', 'players.country=countries.id', array('country_name' => 'name', 'country_iso' => 'iso'))
            ->join('cars', 'car=cars.id', array('car_name' => 'name'), 'left')
            ->join('zones', 'zone=zones.id', array('zone_name' => 'name'));
        $select->where(array('scores.id' => $sub));
        $select->order('scores.zone ASC');
        print_r($select->getSqlString());
    });
```

This should render the following query (which I get right except LIMIT '1' instead of LIMIT 1) :

```
SELECT "scores".*, "players"."name" AS "player_name", "players"."name_url" AS "player_url", "countries"."name" AS "country_name", "countries"."iso" AS "country_iso", "cars"."name" AS "car_name", "zones"."name" AS "zone_name" 
FROM "scores" INNER JOIN "players" ON "player"="players"."id" 
INNER JOIN "countries" ON "players"."country"="countries"."id" 
LEFT JOIN "cars" ON "car"="cars"."id" 
INNER JOIN "zones" ON "zone"="zones"."id"
WHERE "scores"."id" = (SELECT id AS id FROM "scores" AS "temp" WHERE "temp"."glitch" IN ('None', 'Glitch') 
AND temp.zone=scores.zone ORDER BY "temp"."multi" DESC, "temp"."score" DESC LIMIT 1)     
ORDER BY "scores"."zone" ASC
```

Since this doesn't seem to work this way, is there another way I could proceed to get my limit (using Mysql 5 database) ?

EDIT :
Thanks for your help. Finally I figured out a way to get things done the way I want and to remove the quotes by simply remove the subquery construction and to write it directly in the where function :

```
$select->where('scores.id = (SELECT id FROM scores AS lookup WHERE lookup.zone = scores.zone ORDER BY multi DESC , score DESC LIMIT 1)');
```

Although I can continue my dev with this, I feel more like using a poor trick to get rid of this issue and so I will let this question unanswered until someone comes with a real solution there.
Anyway there might be no solution at all, since it might be an issue in ZF2 core itself.

Comment: I think you must be using variable instead of constant 1 in `limit` . If yes, then just cast integer the variable.

Comment: I tried using 1, '1', "1" and a variable (with and without cast) but it gives the same result and there are quotes in final query :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line -

`$select->where(array('scores.id' => $sub));`

with

`$select->where(array('scores.id' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("({$sub->getSqlString($this->tableGateway->adapter->getPlatform())})"));`

Try with just above change.

And if it still doesn't work then make changes to the core `Select` class file located at -

`PROJECT_FOLDER/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Select.php`

1. Line No. 921 - 
   Change `$sql = $platform->quoteValue($limit);` with `$sql = $limit;`
2. Line No. 940 - 
   Change `return array($platform->quoteValue($offset));` with `return array($offset);`

I have come across the issue from github and wondered as why it is still not working with the latest ZF2 files. I know the solution given above doesn't look like the proper one but I had to somehow make it work. I have tried it and it works.

Its only a quick fix before the actual solution comes into picture.

Comment: Haven't thought of this one, tried it but unfortunately that doesn't work, still getting quotes with this.

Comment: Try the new changes to the above answer. The previous answer needed some changes to the core `Select` class file. That was something I did when came across the same scenario as yours. I hope the new answer helps you.

Comment: Indeed, I tried your solution with changes in core Select and it worked. It might seems unadventurous of me, but since I can get rid of the subquery (as in my edit from yesterday) I would rather not change the core Select to avoid unwanted consequences...
So I only checked your solution but will keep the hardcode query in the end.
Anyway thanks a lot for your help, I got to understand some stuff here and your solution might help some in need for a fix there until ZF2 comes with an official one.

Comment: Hi @KunalDethe, greetings! I changed the core files as you instructed but when I execute the query as below the query is still not working as expected. The limit value are ignored!
`$statement = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);`
`$dataSource = $statement->execute();`

Have I done something wrong while executing the statement?